# Why can't you use scientific notation in kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, scientific-notation

I was trying to write a kernel (4.8.1) module, and if I use

```
if (hrtimer_cancel(&hr_timer) == 1) {
         u64 remaining = ktime_to_ns(hrtimer_get_remaining(&hr_timer));
         printk("(%llu ns; %llu us)\n", remaining,
         (unsigned long long) (remaining/1e3));
}
```

it raises this error

```
error: SSE register return with SSE disabled
   printk("\t\t(%llu ns; %llu us)\n",
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          remaining,
          ~~~~~~~~~~
          (unsigned long long) (remaining/1e3));
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

while if I use

```
if (hrtimer_cancel(&hr_timer) == 1) {
         u64 remaining = ktime_to_ns(hrtimer_get_remaining(&hr_timer));
         printk("(%llu ns; %llu us)\n", remaining,
         (unsigned long long) (remaining/1000));
}
```

it works without a problem.

So why can't you use scientific notation in the kernel? I mean, I think is much easier and more readable to use `1e3; 1e6; 1e9` instead of `1000; 1000000; 1000000000`.

Is just a matter of portability/robustness?
Or something like (in this case)

> You need ns? Use `ktime_to_ns`
>   You need us? Use `ktime_to_us`
>   You need ms? Use `ktime_to_ms`

P.S. I tried with a simple .c program and it works without problems

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

void error_handler(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

unsigned long parse_num(const char *number)
{
    unsigned long v;
    char *p;
    errno = 0;

    v = strtoul(number, &p, 10);

    if (errno != 0 || *p != '\0')
        error_handler("parse_num | strtoul");

    return v;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s number_greater_than_1000\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    unsigned long number = parse_num(argv[1]);

    if (number < 1e3 || number > 1e6)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Need to be a number in range (%lu, %lu)\n", (unsigned long) 1e3, (unsigned long) 1e6);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Original: %lu\tScaled: %lu\n", number, (unsigned long) (number/1e3));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I think the main problem is not the notation but the fact that `1e3` is a `double` literal. Floating point is not usually supported in kernels to save time saving registers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSE register return with SSE disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556142/sse-register-return-with-sse-disabled)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1e3` is *not* equivalent to `1000`.

`1000` is an integer constant of type `int`. `1e3` is a floating-point constant of type `double`, equivalent to `1000.0`. That makes `remaining/1e3` a floating-point division, which is what the compiler is complaining about.

See also [SSE register return with SSE disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1556142/827263).